# sforce.connection not working in sites

Tags: visualforce

I have created object using javascript itself without using controller. It is done by using

var cas = new sforce.SObject("Case");
cas.Type = document.getElementById("Type").value;  (mapping the value into the corresponding field
var a = sforce.connection.create([cas]);

case is created when we use insdie salesforce. But when I publish this page in the sites , it is not working.. Please provide me a solution .. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Are you using a public site and trying to create a case?

Comment: yes !!! I am doing that only

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because when you are using public site, no SessionId is generated. 
You can verify this by Adding  {!$Api.Session_ID} on a visualforce page which will print NULL.

Salesforce AJAX toolkit require a session-id to be generates for authentication & authorization of the the request.

If you want to create a case without session Id, you will have to create a controller or a public rest service.

Also you will have to provide the site user profile access to create cases.

If you want to go for rest service, here is a good article on that: [Creating Public Rest Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html).

There was one more detailed article that I read yesterday however I am not able to find the link, I will post the link when I find it.